# How Big is the Download File?

Tags: downloads

I really want to get started using Ubuntu on an old laptop I have, but I have to know the file size. If it's really small, I can use a DVD-RW that I already have lying around. If it's less than 4GB, then I can use either a derpy flash drive, or I can get a larger DVD-RW. Any bigger than 4.7 GB, and I'll have to use the network installer. I would be okay with this, but having a version of Ubuntu on a disc would be best for what I want.

Comment: The Ubuntu 14.04 iso is too large to fit on a CD, so you have to put it on either a DVD or a USB flash drive >=2GB. The official instructions for doing this from ubuntu.com are: [How to burn a DVD on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) and [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Comment: See http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ - the sizes of the images are also listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu iso file is approximately 4.60 GB right now, 18/03/2023

Source: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: That page doesn't say the size of the iso... **AND** wow, clicking on the Download link takes me to a ["Contribute / Donate" page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=14.10&architecture=i386): *"Tell us what we should do more… …and put your money where your mouth is ;)"* While on the bottom-left, NOT in an orange box like the "Pay with Paypal" button, it says *"Not now, take me to the download ›"*. That's a low, sneaky way to try tricking people into paying for Ubuntu, in my opinion.

Comment: When you click the "Not now" link, it will take you to the download page. The ISO file is approximately 980 MBs.

Comment: Then maybe that direct download page should be the one in your answer, if it actually said how big the file is, but it doesn't either. Ubuntu.com seems to hide that info for some reason, most other distros have the size displayed prominently next to the download link, and often a md5 or sha hash too.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 64xbit ISO image is approximately 1.3gb in size. You can also download 32-bit ISO, but it is not recommended if you have a configuration that can run 64-bit.

Link to download : [www.ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Feel free to ask any other question. :)